# Nest js controller method calls twice

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I am using **nest js framework** with **nuts** message broker.

First i have the **Gateway Service** for routing.

**Controller**

```
@ApiOperation({ description: 'Cheking phone and code' })
  @Get('/checkPhoneCode')
  @ApiQuery({ name: 'phone' })
  @ApiQuery({ name: 'code' })
  checkPhoneCode(@Query() phone_with_code: PhoneWithCode) {
    console.log('gateway check phone');
    return this.authenticationService.checkPhoneCode(phone_with_code);
  }
```

**Service**

```
async checkPhoneCode(phone_with_code: PhoneWithCode) {
    console.log('sending nuts request to check phone');
    return this.nats.send('api-gateway.authentication.checkPhoneCode', 
    phone_with_code);
  }
```

Also i have **Auth Service** which awaiting nuts calls to execute operations.

**Controller**

```
 @MessagePattern('api-gateway.authentication.checkPhoneCode')
   checkPhoneCode(phone_with_code: PhoneWithCodeDto) {
    console.log('controller check phone');
    return this.authenticationService.checkPhoneCode(phone_with_code);
  }
```

**Service**

```
 public async checkPhoneCode(phoneCodeDto: PhoneWithCodeDto) {
        const { phone } = phoneCodeDto;
        const { code } = phoneCodeDto;
    
        validator.isMobilePhone(phone);
    
        console.log('sending request');
        const response = await firstValueFrom(
         
          this.httpService.get(
            `https://example.com/method/v1.0/account/checkphonecode/?phone=${phone}&code=${code}`,
          ),
        );
    
        if (!response) {
          return 'error while checking phone code';
        }
    
        if(!response.data.correct){
          return response.data;
        }
    
        return response.data;
        // return this.generatePhoneVaildToken(phone);
      
      }
```

When i call to gateway service the auth method executes twice.
I added console logs to debug and what i saw:

```
api5dev-api-gateway     | gateway check phone
api5dev-api-gateway     | sending nuts request to check phone
api5dev-authentication  | controller check phone
api5dev-authentication  | sending request
api5dev-authentication  | controller check phone
api5dev-authentication  | sending request
```

Why is auth conroller calls twice?

UPD.

In that question i present example of twice calling controlles after nats receive message from service.
But in real seems like that problem along whole application.
Can i add extra settings to NATS to avoid that?
My current config is simple like the official docs presents.

Currently i use simple NATS config:

```
  app.connectMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>({
    transport: Transport.NATS,
    options: {
      servers: ['nats://nats:4222'],
    },
  });
```

Example of sending

```
async getBannersByCityId(cityId: string) {
 const params = { cityId };
 return this.nats.send('api-gateway.common.getBannersById', 
 params);
}
```

Example of receive

```
@MessagePattern('api-gateway.common.getBannersById')
 getBannersByCityId(getBanners: GetBannerByCityIdDto) {
 console.log('banner list');
 return this.bannerService.getBannersByCityId(getBanners);
}
```

Client settings :

```
ClientsModule.register([
  {
    name: 'COMMON_SERVICE',
    transport: Transport.NATS,
  },
]),
```

In that config i found that  **getBannersByCityId(getBanners: GetBannerByCityIdDto)** emitted twice

Maybe i need to config additinal headers https://docs.nats.io/using-nats/developer/develop_jetstream/model_deep_dive ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the way the [`@MessagePattern` decorator](https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/basics#request-response) is used could potentially lead to duplicate handling of the message: you would need to make sure that the pattern specified in the `@MessagePattern` decorator is *unique* across the application. Duplicate patterns can lead to a single message being consumed by *multiple* handlers, hence the `auth` method executed twice.

For that, prefix all your message patterns with a unique namespace related to the service.
For example, if you have an `AuthenticationService` and a `UserService`, make sure all message patterns in the `AuthenticationService` start with `auth`, and those in the `UserService` start with `user`. That prevents any accidental overlap in pattern names.

Example:

```js
// In AuthenticationService
@MessagePattern('auth.checkPhoneCode')
checkPhoneCode(phone_with_code: PhoneWithCodeDto) {
  // Implementation
}

// In UserService
@MessagePattern('user.checkPhoneCode')
checkUserPhoneCode(phone_with_code: PhoneWithCodeDto) {
  // Implementation
}
```

Make your operation names within the patterns as descriptive as possible. Instead of generic terms like `check`, use specific terms that describe the action and the entity it operates on.

```js
@MessagePattern('auth.verifyPhoneNumberAndCode')
verifyPhoneNumberAndCode(phone_with_code: PhoneWithCodeDto) {
  // Implementation
}
```

That pattern is more specific than just `checkPhoneCode`, reducing the likelihood of unintentional pattern matching.

---

> But yes the message is unique.
> For example `api-gateway.authentication.checkPhoneCode` - service `api-gateway`, module `authentication`, method `checkPhoneCode`. All separated by comma.
> Only authentication service receives authentication messages. In my archihecture the module name of gateway is the service name in receiver.

That means the issue of methods being called twice is not due to non-unique `@MessagePattern` identifiers, but rather, it might be related to the way [NATS](https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/nats) is configured or how messages are being processed within their system. Review the NATS server logs for any anomalies or errors related to message delivery can provide insights into what might be causing the duplicates.

If messages are being processed more than once, implementing deduplication strategies can help. That involves checking if the message has been processed before by maintaining a cache of processed message IDs or unique attributes (I do not see any NATS' built-in deduplication features).

You mention [JetStream](https://github.com/nats-io/nats.js?tab=readme-ov-file#jetstream) and additional headers. JetStream provides enhanced capabilities for NATS: check if [Jetstream](https://github.com/nats-io/nats.deno/blob/5573625badb8ea4ce5a9cff32af9e714e22c9694/jetstream.md) includes message deduplication: within JetStream, consumers can be configured with specific options to control how messages are delivered and acknowledged. That includes settings that might help prevent duplicate processing, such as message acknowledgment policies and delivery attempts.

Make sure the message acknowledgment behavior is correctly implemented. In a system where messages are acknowledged manually, it is important to acknowledge the message only after successful processing to prevent it from being re-delivered and processed again.

Also, if the service unintentionally subscribes to the same subject more than once, this could lead to duplicate processing. Inspect the code for multiple subscription instances or accidental re-subscriptions.

Comment: Thanks.But yes the message is unique. For example api-gateway.authentication.checkPhoneCode - service  api-gateway, module authentication, method checkPhoneCode . All separated by comma. Only authentication service recieves authentication messages. In my archihecture the module name of gateway is the service name in reciever.When does not the  separate service then expected reciver common service

Comment: thanks for help. The real problem was in overrided send method...

Answer (score 1):

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ClientProxy } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { timeout } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { lastValueFrom } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class NatsService {
  constructor(
    @Inject('LAZAR_MESSAGE_BUS') private readonly clientNats: ClientProxy,
  ) {}

  // eslint-disable-next-line no-magic-numbers
  public async send<R = any, E = any>(
    route: string,
    entityData: E,
    pipeTimeoutMs = 60000,
  ): Promise<R> {
    const observable = this.clientNats
      .send<R, E>(route, entityData)
      .pipe(timeout(pipeTimeoutMs));

    const entity: R | undefined = await lastValueFrom(observable);

    if (entity && entity['error']) {
      throw new Error(`${entity['error']['message']}}`);
    }
  
    //return  await lastValueFrom(observable); Promblem here
    return entity;
  }

  public async emit<R = any, E = any>(
    route: string,
    entityData: E,
  ): Promise<void> {
    this.clientNats.emit<R, E>(route, entityData);
  }
}
```

The real problem was in overrided send method which observe twice instead of return firstValueFrom(observeble)